# Curl Command response output has new line and Extra characters

Tags: shell, unix, curl

I am using below curl command to download file from url. But the output file has new line and extra characters due to which Tiff file getting corrupt.

```
 curl -k -u Username:Password URL >/Test.Tiff
```

Sample Test.Tiff has below data

```
1.
2.
3.IDCFILE87918       
4.II*ÿûÞ©¥zKÿJÛï_]ÿÿÿ÷ÿÞï¹×ëÿ¤ÿO]
5¿ûÕÿÿ¯zê¿ß£0•¿þÛ¯kÚÿ¹5Éöûé_u_éwÕzkJï·_¯¯ßþýuw]í~þžmúºßÿzÈfçúîC7½õëÿÛ¯ô¿Z[6.ý®Úö·4ýý ~«v×ÿº^Ÿ¿í¾Ýÿzuýëÿ÷×]}ûÿõé‰ÿ¿m/KûÿµÛ_ý¾×Oín½}+wýzíýö¿õÿî—7.ékñN¿û­Sß¦=ºì%±N—í¯i_Û¶¬:×·m{
8.ÿ­¶ÿím¿í/ívÒ®ÒP­¯Õ¥¶¿}SÛúì%Ú_kûim­ú«i·V½»
9..Âýt•¿ßoÛ]¦Òý´»KßØaPaa…å87M…VÂúý?ÿa„˜ei
```

First three lines where line no 1 and 2 is newlines which is coming as ^M through VI editor are extra which should not be there.When i delete first 3 lines and save the file then i am able to open the file.

Let me know how first three lines are getting appended.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Try `grep`ing the Curl output to remove blank lines, like this:

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> <url> | grep -v '^$' > /Test.Tiff
```

Curl also has the `--output <name>` option to redirect output to a file. You may first output the response to a file and then use it as `grep` input:

```
curl -k -u <username>:<password> <url> > curl_out.txt
grep -v '^$' curl_out.txt > Test.Tiff
```

Comment: You can also use `| grep .` to remove empty lines.

Comment: @peterRepeater: neither `grep .` nor `grep '.'` remove empty lines for me. Which grep binary, version and OS are you using?